# sum elements of matrix and calculate the average of the i-th line

Tags: c

Hi all i have a problem with this exercise in Language C.
The exercise is:
Given a matrix write a function that:
A) Calculate and return the sum of the elements.
B) Calculate and return the average of the i-th line
I did my own procedure but i have a lot errors.
My procedure is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
int n=10;
int m=10;
int i;
int j;
int mat [i][j];
int sum=0;
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    for (j=0; j<m;j++)
        sum=sum+mat[i][j];}
printf("The sum of all elements of matrix is:%d",sum);
somma=0;
for (j=0;j<m;i++){
    sum=sum+mat[i][j];
    sum=sum/m
        printf("The average of i-th line is:%d",sum);
 }
}
```

i think that i have to put scanf somewhere but i don't know where.
I hope that you can help me
thank you!

Comment: C has no procedures.:) It seems you need to write two separate functions.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow [tag:c] has procedures: `void foo (...)`

Comment: can you show me please? tomorrow i have exam ç_ç

Comment: [In case of fixed size matrix](http://ideone.com/DS5vdM)

Comment: [In case of variable size matrix](http://ideone.com/89G4fP)

Comment: @LPs C does not have procedures. You showed an example of a function.

Comment: You never initialized the values in `mat`.

Answer (score 1):

You declare a matrix with undefined  sizes

```
int mat [i][j];
```

where `i` and `j` are uninitizlized.

You probably want

```
int mat [n][m];
```

Moreover your matrix should be inizialized with values, otherwise you'll get the sum of stack garbage.

At the end, a possible solution is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 2;
    int m = 2;
    int i;
    int j;
    int mat[n][m];
    int sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("Insert value of mat[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            sum = sum + mat[i][j];
        }
    }

    printf("The sum of all elements of matrix is: %d\n", sum);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            sum = sum + mat[i][j];
        }
        sum = sum / m;
        printf("The average of line %d is: %d\n", i, sum);
    }
}
```

As you can see I changed the average calculation:

1. First of all you wrote a `j` loop incrementing `i`
2. You must loop for all lines, so you must add a for loop that inc rows
3. sum must be reset each time you calculate the row average

take notes that the average is calculated using integers, so no decimals will be available.

Comment: Did you add init values? Did you changed the average as shown? In altre parole hai letto l'intera risposta?

Comment: @PietroDimichele What error message did you get? Are you using C99 or later C compiler?

Comment: @LPs tutto chiaro, però mi da errore se lo eseguo anche con il tuo nuovo programma

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i'm using visual studio, the errors are:Error 1 error C2057: expected constant expression .Error2error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0.Error 3error C2087: 'mat' : missing subscript. Error4error C2133: 'mat' : unknown size

Comment: @PietroDimichele The C compiler you are using does not support VLA(as `int mat [n][m]`). one way Change `int n=10;
int m=10;` to  `enum { n=10,  m=10};` then `int mat[n][m];`

Comment: You got your answer then.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it's working! but the program close immediately when i put all elements of matrix, how can avoid this?

Comment: @PietroDimichele Put to last such as `system("PAUSE");` or `char ch;`... `printf("enter q\n"); scanf(" %c", &ch);`